# PHP downsides of storing mysql PDO connection using define

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, constants

What are the downsides of storing mysql PDO connection using `define`? For instance,

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASS', 'xxx' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'xxx' ); 
define( 'DSN', 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME );
```

I have been thinking to use `const` just like [this example](http://gonzalo123.com/2011/01/10/using-php-classes-to-store-configuration-data/) but there are limitation of it.

For instance,

1. I can't do `'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME` with `const`.
2. I can't do these below with const as well,

(other config info...)

```
define ( 'WEBSITE_DOCROOT', str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/' );

define( 'SCHEME', isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://' );
```

`define` seems to fit the purpose, but I am not sure how safe it is and any thing I should be aware of for using define for store setting info? Any advice?

Another option is storing them in a class,

```
$config = array(
    'DB_USER' => 'root',
    'DB_PW' => 'password'
);
```

But there are said with this option, `the end user can screw the file and break the entire app`(taken from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236976/best-practice-for-configuration-files-in-a-website)). How the user can screw the file?

Comment: `const` resides inside classes.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you `define` will be available to all parts of your PHP code which could be a security risk. If you use variables you can limit the exposure of data because the variables are of limited scope.

> But there are said with this option, the end user can screw the file and break the entire app(taken from here). How the user can screw the file?

This post is not talking about user in terms of website user, but rather as a user of the code itself (e.g. someone using an open source project and editing the configuration).

Comment: `e.g. someone using an open source project and editing the configuration` - how `editing the configuration` can screw the file and break the entire app?